# Restrict FTP user to access only its own directory and Download Only

Tags: shell, solaris, ftp

I need to create a user which can only FTP to specific directory and download data from it only no upload or delete files.

After searching on line I reached to following points

1. useradd -g 10 -d /data/ -m -s /bin/bash myftp
2. Run ftpconfig -d /data/
3. in /etc/ftpd/ftpaccess update as below:

   guestuser       myftp
4. update /etc/ftpd/ftpaccess as below:

   delete          no              anonymous,guest

   upload class=guestuser * /data/ no myftp staff nodirs
5. Run "in.ftpd -a"

But i saw following directories got created in user folder, Please suggest any better alternatives

```
d--x--x--x   2 root     sys          512 Mar 23 12:52 dev
d--x--x--x   5 root     sys          512 Mar 23 12:52 etc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     bin            9 Mar 23 12:52 bin -> ./usr/bin
d--x--x--x   2 root     bin          512 Mar 23 12:52 lib
d--x--x--x   6 root     sys          512 Mar 23 12:52 usr
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Mar 23 12:52 pub
```

Comment: Are you talking about sftp or ftp? You mention sftp, but you run ftp server.

Comment: I am looking for ftp, sorry for confusion, i will edit.

Comment: I think you have created a chrooted environment, so that the user can see the system as if he is in it, but he is just in the root cage. I don't know about ftp, I have done it with sftp. There you can have just a couple of directories for in and out files and that's it. You can avoid the user sshing to the system setting his default shell as /usr/sbin/nologin. That way he can only sftp to the system and he will only see the directories for in and out.

Comment: Please share your steps

Comment: There are plenty of guides out there, you can find one in https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu Remember to modify your /etc/passwd and change user's shell to /usr/sbin/nologin to avoid the use of ssh.